# Hyperledger V1.0 Endorsement policies Failing for AND Condition

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying the Hyperledger fabric-samples/first-network sample. I am working with 3 nodes. I am testing with different endorsement policies while instantiating the chaincode. The instantiation is successful. However, when I invoke the chaincode, it is failing. Only the one OR condition is working.

Here is the list of options i tried with the output result.

- `-P "OR ('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member','Org3MSP.member'))"` -Response **Success**
- `-P "OR ('Org1MSP.member', AND('Org2MSP.member','Org3MSP.member'))"` -Response **Failed**
- `-P "AND ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member','Org3MSP.member')"`
  -Response Status **Failed**
- `-P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org3MSP.member'))"` -Response **Failed**
- `-P "AND ('Org1MSP.member','Org3MSP.member'))"` -Response **Failed**

Please help me in solving the endorsement policy issue.

Answer (score 2):

For endorsement policies that require signatures from N peers, you have to first collect the signatures from all those peers and then submit a TX.

The Hyperledger Fabric SDKs (at least node SDK) lets you do that. The `peer` CLI currently won't.

If you **are** using one of the Hyperledger Fabric SDKs, then we'll need details of the environment and logs to debug.

Hope this helps!